# Insert algorithm in Lyx 2.1.1 with line numbers

Tags: algorithm, latex, lyx

I am able to insert algorithms directly with Lyx 2.1.1  using insert->float->algorithm , however the algorithm lines are not numbered in the generated pdf. Is there any option that can number the algorithm lines or any work around to include algorithm in Lyx with line number? I am using the built in IEEE template document in Lyx and assume it should be possible with other templates too.

Answer (score 3):

The default algorithm insertion is just a floating environment. If you want a built-in numbered algorithm, you have to consider adding the [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) module:

[image]

Then, also add `\LinesNumbered` to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.

[image]

The above assumes a non-ERT approach to numbered-line algorithms. Of course, if you wish, you can go all out with LaTeX ERT to obtain line numbers in algorithms.

Comment: the \LinesNumbered when added to the LaTeX Preamble causes 'undefined control sequence' error

Comment: @Shan: Since version 4.0 of [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) there has been some updates to the interface (see section **5 Compatibility issues**, p 16 of the [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf)). `\LinesNumbered` used to be called `\linesnumbered` (which you can try). My suggestion would be that you actually update your distribution to include the most recent version of packages; it'll be better in the long run. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Answer (score 3):

I think a better way is to even use the package *algorithmic* by adding the following in **Documents -> Settings... -> LaTex Preambule**:

> `\usepackage{algorithmic}`

And then, inside the default *Algorithm* float as **Tex Code**:

> `\begin{algorithmic}[1]`
>
> `\STATE`  *example line that will be numbered*
>
> `\end{algorithmic}`

This solved the problem for me. I hope it does the same for you!

Answer (score 0):

After having inserted the float, you should additionally insert a program listing environment. In the settings dialog of it (which you reach through the context menu of the listing), you can set numbering, highlighting and the other most important things the LaTeX package 'lstlistings' supports. (Rest of the settings can put in into the second tab of the dialog)